# regex with format 07BP13223

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can some one give me a regex with format 07BP13223

07: 2 numeric digits

BP: 2 chars (always the same)

13223: 5 numeric digits

Comment: What have you tried yourself to solve this problem? Stack Overflow is not a regex drive-through. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ is a good place to start learning regular expressions (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions for JavaScript specifically (more concise too)). You basically just need to know how a digit is represented in a regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use: `/\d{2}BP\d{5}/`
Experiment with it to learn how it works as well. Regex is a great skill to have and I highly suggest playing around with it. 
Here is a link to Regex101 with this regex already inserted that you can play with: [Regex101 Link](https://regex101.com/r/l6KpJc/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `/\d\dBP\d{5}/`.

It will look for 2 digits (`\d`), followed by the litteral `BP`, followed by 5 digits `\d{5}`.

Comment: Please may you not answer questions which just ask for code to be written for them? Especially when the OP hasn't shown any effort.